# Return named function from constructor function

Tags: javascript

I've never seen this syntax done before, but it's used all throughout the Angular source code.

```
function something() {
    // do stuff...
    return function foo() {
        // do stuff..
    };
}

// later
var x = something();
```

From what I can tell `foo()` is being used as a closure function, but why does the function have a name? I thought giving a closure function a name was invalid syntax, but this appears to run fine in the browser.

Is there anything different between the above and below code? if so, what?

```
function something() {
    // do stuff...
    return function() {
        // do stuff..
    };
}

// later
var x = something();
```

Comment: well, since you arent executing the function, x in the bottom example would be a function definition would it it not?  It is possibly a use which maintains a scope for processing data, as certain variables are still in the scope, it is just moved elsewhere?   I too, would like enlightenment where possible. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the function being included in a closure.

There is a real difference between a **function declaration**:

```
function myFunc() { /* ... */ }
```

and a **function expression**:

```
var myFunc = function() { /* ... */ };
```

or

```
var myObj = {
    myFunc: function() { /* ... */ },
    // ...
}
```

In these cases, the function expressions were anonymous.  What you're discussing is a **named function expression**:

```
var myFunc = function privateName() { /* ... */ };
```

(Note that the internal `privateName` does not have to match `myFunc`.)

These have two distinct advantages over anonymous ones, and one disadvantage.  The disadvantage is that:

- IE, at least through IE8, created two copies of such functions 
  for every one you meant to create.

The advantages are:

- The names show up in debuggers, making it easier to find your way around.
- The names are available inside the function, and nowhere else, so you can use them for
  recursion or other internal usage without polluting the global namespace and without 
  depending on deprecated features like `argument.callee`.

**[Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/)** wrote perhaps the definitive article on them: **[Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)**.

Comment: The IE "disadvantage" is only a problem if you've got a name conflict because of it. If you're expecting IE, allow for that, otherwise make full use of them!

Comment: A "function declaration" is still a valid expression, though.  It evaluates to the function.  What you want to highlight is the distinction between **named** and **anonymous** function expressions.

Comment: do named functions have anything to do with the prototype of the current object?

Comment: @PaulS: If you read kangax's article, you might decide that this is more of a disadvantage, even in an IE-only situation.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog: You're right.  The prolog of this was overlong.  There was probably no real reason to dwell on the difference between Function Declarations and Function Expressions, when the real question was simply the difference between Named and Anonymous Function Expressions.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: No.  These are unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 3):

An *named function expression* is a cool thing that allows you to ease caching and calls from withing that same function (a recursive call).

For instance what if you wanted to know how many times a function has been called:

```
var anonNamedFn = function fn() {
    fn.cache = fn.cache || {
        callCount: 0
    };

    fn.cache.callCount += 1;
};
```

Another example with recursion:

```
var anonNamedFn = function fn(n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return fn(n-1);
    }
};
```

**It allows a disambiguation of `this` context.**

**UPDATE**

**It helps at debugging, since it shows the name of your function if you choose a wise one**

Be careful though, because only true browsers support well this feature (IE9+ for IE).

**EDIT**
Anonymous named function => named function expression [Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s)

Comment: But.. it's not anonymous if it's got a name

Comment: Yes that's the thing I love about rainbows

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is _named function expression_ (using `function` as an operator).